# Unable to run Chrome browser on Android by using Appium and RobotFramework

Tags: appium, robotframework

Unable to run the Chrome browser on Android by using Appium and  RobotFramework
What I have tried so far:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Loign_To_Weekend
   App_Up_And_Run

*** Keywords ***
App_Up_And_Run
    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android deviceName=RNNNNNNNK  browserName=Chrome
    Go To Url  https://www.amazon.com/
```

but after installing appium settings app, not opening the chrome browser and it's showing error like below, both suggested links are invalid

> WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred
> while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found
> that can automate Chrome '10
> 2.0.5005'. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature. See
> https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-a
> ppium/web/chromedriver.md for more details Stacktrace: UnknownError:
> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome
> '102.0.5005'. You  could also try to enable automated chromedrivers
> download server feature. See
> https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chrom
> edriver.md for more details
> at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
> at asyncHandler (C:\Users\acb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)

I'm not sure where I made the mistake, thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

You must have chromedriver.exe in your Windows machine, for the correct version of Chrome in the Android phone.

You download the version for `Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '102.0.5005'`.

You pass the path for chromedriver.exe to the Appium server, in the starting command or in capabilities.

On Appium Desktop, Advanced Tab, you find the `Chromedriver Binary Path` field.